# combining two variables together, including NA

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to combine two binary variables together as a single variable, so if there is a 0 in one and a 1 in the other it would be a 1. This contains NAs. Example

```
a <- c("A", NA, 0)
b <- c("B",0,  1)
c <- c("C", 0, 0)
d <- c("D", 0, 1)
e <- c("E", NA, NA)
aa<- rbind(a,b,c,d,e)
aa <- as.data.frame(aa)
```

I would like to code this to give me:

```
a <- c("A", NA, 0, 0)
b <- c("B",0,  1, 1)
c <- c("C", 0, 0, 0)
d <- c("D", 0, 1, 1)
e <- c("E", NA, NA, NA)
bb<- rbind(a,b,c,d, e)
bb <- as.data.frame(bb)
```

I think this is an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `base R`, use `rowSums` to create the V4 column by comparing the columns of interest with 1 and then replace the values in 'V4' to NA where there are all NAs in a row in columns 2 and 3

```
aa$V4 <- rowSums(aa[-1] == 1,  na.rm = TRUE)
aa$V4[rowSums(is.na(aa[2:3])) == 2] <- NA
```

-output

```
> aa
  V1   V2   V3 V4
a  A <NA>    0  0
b  B    0    1  1
c  C    0    0  0
d  D    0    1  1
e  E <NA> <NA> NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` like such. Note that I use `type.convert` before because some of your columns are character while they should be numeric:

```r
library(dplyr)
aa %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(V4 = ifelse(if_all(c(V2, V3), is.na), NA, 
                     rowSums(across(c(V2, V3)), na.rm = TRUE)))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#a  A NA  0  0
#b  B  0  1  1
#c  C  0  0  0
#d  D  0  1  1
#e  E NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aa$V4 <- as.character(ifelse(rowSums(is.na(aa),na.rm = TRUE)>1,NA,
                rowSums(aa==1,na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** to generalize the `coalesce` idea we could write a custom function and the apply it:

```
my_function <- function(x, y) {
  case_when(is.na(x) & !is.na(y) ~ y,
            is.na(y) & !is.na(x) ~ x,
            x==1 & y==0 ~ x,
            x==y ~ x,
            x==0 | is.na(x) & y==1 ~ y)
}

aa %>% 
  mutate(V4 = my_function(V2, V3))

#tested with this example dataset: 
V2 <- c(NA, 0, 1)
V3 <- c(NA, 0, 1)

expand.grid(V2, V3) %>% 
  rename(V2 = Var1, V3 = Var2) %>% 
  mutate(V4 = my_function(V2, V3))
```

output:

```
  V1   V2   V3   V4
a  A <NA>    0    0
b  B    0    1    1
c  C    0    0    0
d  D    0    1    1
e  E <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

**First answer:**
We could use `coalesce` for the provided data:

Note this might not work if you change data:
The rule is the order of the columns: 0 must be before NA and 1 must be before 0:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(V4 = coalesce(V3, V2))

  V1   V2   V3   V4
a  A <NA>    0    0
b  B    0    1    1
c  C    0    0    0
d  D    0    1    1
e  E <NA> <NA> <NA>
```